Webp Image is not loading on browser?
When I run the following html file on google chrome, the image that I linked into the html code doesn't load. All that appears is a small image icon which isn't the original code. A similar thing happens when I try to open the image in vscode. Since vscode has the function where you can click on the link to a image, I tried to do that, but instead of showing the image, it just says: An error occurred when loading the image. The image file is called "undevelopedsite.webp". This is the html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Sorry, this page is still in development</p>
    <img src="undevelopedsite.webp" > 
  </body>
</html>

I have tried using different images and different image formats, but that hasn't made a difference. I checked my code, and there doesn't seem to be any syntax errors, so I don't know what else to do.

If you have the HTL document and the image in the same folder, it can hardly be a path issue. Have you checked if the browser console has any related errors or warnings to show? What do you see when you switch to the network panel, do you see a request for the image being made? If so, what response is it getting (status code)? If vscode also can't display the image (and the access happens via the file system in that scenario, not HTTP) - then most likely your image file itself has issues.

As well an ensuring your html file and .webp file are in the same directory, and that the filename match your code exactly, have you tried opening the .webp file directly in the browser itself to ensure it's actually a valid image file that the browser can display?

Your code looks perfect, I tried with a webp image and it worked. It seems like the image that you have is likely to be a corrupt image. Please try to download a fresh image and use that. Make sure that the image and html file is placed in the same folder.
